# Help identifying weird component (sensor)

Tags: sensor, identification, components

[image: Unknown sensor component]

I have this salvaged part, with an unknown source. I am trying to identify what exactly this could be.  Due to the clear casing my guess would be some kind of a light sensor, but googling for those PCB markings, or using reverse image search, I came up with nothing.

There is a small die within the case, and another strip of black something.

There is a logo I think, with a "circled W." I can't come up with any brand I am familiar with.

Can you help me identify this component?

Comment: Looks like in interior of an optical mouse.

Comment: You have a point, however it is not from a mouse, that much I know 100%.

Comment: Maybe something like an autofocus sensor. What *do* you know about the origin, since  you know it is not from a mouse? Withholding information is generally not helpful.

Comment: Then in the package there is an led and the long black thing is a linear displacement photodiode (see https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/product/optical-sensors/distance-position-sensor/psd.html)

Comment: Some op-amp with photodiode were also "transparent" from TI, a long time ago (but with 8 pins).